# Promise.then() firing on SequelizeUniqueConstraintError

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I am a little new to promises and Sequelize. I am trying to insert a new user to my SQLite-database using constraint. In the `User`-model I have flagged the `email`-property as `unique`, however when this constraint is not met the code inside the `.then()`-block is still executed.

Code:

```js
User.create({
   email: uname,
   password: psw
})
   .then(console.log('success'))
   .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
```

Output:

```
Success
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `users` ...
{ SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation Error ... }
```

No entry is of course added to the DB.

Expected output (when inserting unique value):

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `users` ...
success
```

Expected output (when inserting duplicate value):

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `users` ...
{ SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation Error ... }
```

Any help would be *very* welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your mistake now:

```
User.create({
   email: uname,
   password: psw
})
   .then(console.log('success'))
   .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
```

What you're doing here, is that instead of **passing a function to the then()**, you're **executing a function**. Of course it will run :D Change it to this:

```
User.create({
   email: uname,
   password: psw
})
   .then(()=>{console.log('success')})
   .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
```

Comment: Haha, I feel like a complete idiot right now. Thank you so much, you're a life saver!